# Is this :$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sigma_{k}(n)}{n!} $ irrational series for every natural number $k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility, divisor-sum

Is this: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sigma_{k}(n)}{n!} $$ irrational series for every natural number $k$?

Where : $\sigma_{k}(n)=\sigma(\sigma(\sigma(\dots n)))$ is the $k$-th iterate of the sum of divisors function.

**Note** : I know only it  is for $k=1$ and $k=2$

Thank you for any help .

Comment: How do you compute $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sigma(\sigma(n))}{n!}$$?

Comment: I understand that: $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sum_{d\mid n}d}{n!}=\sum_{d\geq 1}d\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{1}{(dm)!}=\sum_{d\geq 1}\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}\left(\exp\left(\exp\frac{2\pi k i}{d}\right)-1\right).$$

Comment: I don't know for it's evaluation, only i know that it is irrational for k=1 and k=2 , i think the result established by Erdos and peter Browenien ,that's all what i knwo

Comment: I think Erdos established the irrationality of this series :$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{d(n)}{2^n}$$